# Send Email from MS Project via Outlook

Tags: vba, email, outlook, ms-project

I am trying to open and populate emails from MS Project via Outlook. I have done this before from Excel, but when I drop the code into Project I get an error.

```
'Create and Set New Mail Item
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(OutlookMailItem)
```

The error triggers on the Dim OutlookApp line and reads, 'User-Defined Type Not Defined'

What am I forgetting here?

Comment: Tools => References and tick *Microsoft Outlook ??.? Object Library*

Comment: Yes! I forgot 'Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library'. I knew it was going to be something obvious.   Thanks,

Comment: You could also replace both `Outlook.Aplication` and `Outlook.MailItem` with `Object` this way you will be doing late binding, and thus the reference to Outlook library won't be needed anymore, regardless of the application you run your code in. You would also have to replace the constant `OutlookMailItem` with `0` (it's actual value) in the call to `CreateItem`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the requirement, so I'm sending a blind shot.   In Project 2007 you'll see a combo box at the top right of the screen, probably defaulting to "All Tasks". Choose the date range you want with the info you need and send this to your team along with any encouraging words that you need to motivate them.

Will this help?